# Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header doesn't let me switch pages after log in

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am able to log in using a tablet or phone(as an app) but I can't log in when I use my PC. The error returns as:

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://softwarehuttest.x10.mx/public/account/login/?id=&password=&. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

I tried to correct the error by using the following header:

Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://softwarehuttest.x10.mx/public/account/login/"

I am now able to log in on my PC now with one problem. It used to log in and immediately switch to my home page on success. When I added the header, it logs in but no longer switches to my homepage.

Please advice what is missing. Thanks.

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://softwarehuttest.x10.mx/public/account/login/"    
//LOGGING IN AND GOING TO HOME PAGE ON SUCCESS
$(document).on("pageinit", "#loginForm", function () {
    $("#form1").on("submit", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "http://softwarehuttest.x10.mx/public/account/login/",
            data: $("#form1").serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                if (data.loggedIn) {
                    $.mobile.changePage("#home");
                } else {
                    alert("You entered the wrong username or password. Please try again.");
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: This is due to the [Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.com/wiki/Same-origin_policy). You can only make an AJAX request to the same domain, unless you use JSONP or CORS.

Comment: I was under the impression that adding the header resolves the same origin policy. I only need it to work on a mobile phone/tablet at the end but right now, debugging is exhausting w/o being able to use my PC.

Answer (score 0):

This is a cross domain issue. So you have two options, either your service supports JSONP or you'll have to create your own proxy. Regarding the last option, you can make an Ajax request to your own script (in Java, PHP, etc) that will call your original request (http://softwarehuttest.x10.mx/public/account/login/). Then you'll have to handle the answer and forward back.